# Table migration error in Laravel for adding a column to the table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I used Laravel 8.0 and I wanted to create the table. At first, I give the command `php artisan make:migration create_products_table --table='products'` and after that `php artisan migrate`.

At this moment the table `products` was created but I wanted to add the column of the products.

So I add column with this `$table->string('type', 100)` and I migrate again but it shows "nothing to migrate" and the table doesn't change its structure. So I guessed it might be the problem of Laravel version and create the project with Laravel 7.0 but the same happens.
I am not sure the reason. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: your migration only runs once. Check your migration table. You have two options here. First one is to create a migration for every column you add (Technically this is what you would do in production). Second one is to add columns to previous migration and run `hp artisan migrate:fresh`. This will drop all columns along with the data.

Answer (score 0):

because it is already registered in your migration table. So you have to do two things

1. from your migrations table delete the products row
2. then delete your products table

now run `php artisan migrate` now you can see your changes

Answer (score -1):

since your modified your table you need to rollback just one step back for the last process you did for your table.

`php artisan migrate:rollback` this will drop the old table and allows you to migrate the new one again

the other option is to drop everything(seeds, data, tables , fakers etc) and migrate

`php artisan migrate:fresh`